# How to handle autocomplete list in webdriver?

Tags: select, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

How to select country name from auto-complete drop down list?

Please provide suggestion with code for Google search so that i can understand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your dropdown is editable you can directly type the values using send keys, else you need to simulate the Arrow down key actions as you needed. But it not wise once, because if new values are added in the drop down(Anyway in this case, there will be fixed because the number of countries is a constant),then it will get messed.

```
driver.findElement(locator).sendKeys(countryName , Keys.TAB);
```

or

```
driver.findElement(locator).sendKeys(Keys.DOWN);
```

Comment: this works fine 
    driver.findElement(locator).sendKeys(Keys.DOWN);

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
WebElement dropdown = driver.findElement(By.....);
Select dropdownSelect = new Select(dropdown);
dropdownSelect.selectByVisibleText(itemStr) or selectByValue(value);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Link : http://www.mythoughts.co.in/2012/05/getting-google-search-auto-suggestions.html#.Ul-lJdi1Zbc
@Test  
  public void SearchSuggestion() {  

  driver.get("http://google.com");  
  driver.findElement(By.id("gbqfq")).sendKeys("vam");  
  driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);  

   WebElement table = driver.findElement(By.className("gssb_m"));   
   List<webelement> rows = table.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));   
   Iterator<webelement> i = rows.iterator();   
   System.out.println("-----------------------------------------");   
   while(i.hasNext()) {   
           WebElement row = i.next();   
           List<webelement> columns = row.findElements(By.tagName("td"));   
           Iterator<webelement> j = columns.iterator();   
           while(j.hasNext()) {   
                   WebElement column = j.next();   
                   System.out.println(column.getText());   
           }   
           System.out.println("");   

   System.out.println("-----------------------------------------");   
   }   
  }   
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
driver.findElement(By.id("your searchBox")).sendKeys("your partial keyword");
Thread.sleep(3000);
List <WebElement> listItems = driver.findElements(By.xpath("your list item locator"));
listItems.get(0).click();
driver.findElement(By.id("your searchButton")).click()
```