# Selenium - How can i select value from auto complete drop down

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

```
<div class="cityLocaDiv1 col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
  <input class="form-control" id="city-locality1" placeholder="Enter City or Locality" type="text">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down cityicon1" style="position:absolute;cursor:pointer;"></span>
</div>
```

[image]

How can I write the selenium code using Java

i)Select locality AECS, Bangalore (Locality input should be dynamic, i.e. it should be able to change the test data at any time)

Comment: Looks like you're asking someone to write code for you. Show code you've tried already and issue description

Comment: Its better to show your code here to get a help. May be you get an idea from this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17423947/how-to-handle-autocomplete-list-in-webdriver

Comment: This question is more like to How to give run time test data. Right ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this way. In below code suppose first i enter the city name as `Mumbai` so dropdwn will showing me name with `Mumbai` city.

My next step will be wait until, The city that i want to click from dropdown so, i have used `explicit wait`.

After perform click action on city name as `Mumbai Central, Mumbai`

```
driver.get("http://www.medinfi.com");
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);    
driver.findElement(By.id("city-locality1")).sendKeys("Mumbai"); 
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 15);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='cityLocaDiv1 col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12']/ul[@id='autoCityResult1']/li/a[contains(text(), 'Mumbai Central, Mumbai')]"))));
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='cityLocaDiv1 col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12']/ul[@id='autoCityResult1']/li/a[contains(text(), 'Mumbai Central, Mumbai')]")).click();
```

Comment: How can I change the test data anytime if at all i want to ?

Comment: Simply change the city name as `Mumbai`, along with that you need to create xpath based on dropdown search result.

Comment: Does my explanation of code `helped` you? if it does then please mark this answer as `Accepted`

Answer (score 0):

Try the below it might work.

```
driver.get("http://www.medinfi.com");
driver.findElement("city-locality1").sendKeys("Mumbai",Keys.DOWN);
```